# What's the problem with this backslash in SOQL query?

Tags: soql, rest, dynamic-soql

I'm receiving a String query with query params (via URL), and one is mandatory and seven are optional. So if i don't receive a param, shouldn't be included in the query.

For instance:

My **code** is:

```
List<customObject__c> lstCstObj = [SELECT customField1__c, customField2__c, customField3__c, customField4__c, customField5__c FROM customObject__c WHERE customField2__c =: strVar1 + strCondition];
```

The value of **strVar1** is the result of:

```
String.valueOf(RestContext.request.params.get('name'));
```

The value of **strSurname** is:

```
String strSurname = String.valueOf(RestContext.request.params.get('surname'));
```

And that give us the value of The value of **strCondition** (here is the problem) wich is:

```
String strCondition = '';    
{...}
if(strSurname !=null){
   strCondition = strCondition + ' AND (customField3__c =\''+ strSurname+ '\' OR customField3__c =\'' + strSurname+ '\' OR customField3__c =\''+ strSurname+'\')';
}
```

So if i write that **it works**, but obviously i can't because it's not a fixed value, depends of the query param:

```
SELECT customField1__c, customField2__c, customField3__c FROM customObject__c WHERE customField2__c =: strVar1 AND (customField3__c ='Doe' OR customField4__c='Doe' OR customField5__c='Doe')
```

The **log** returns:

```
strCondition:  AND (customField3__c ='Doe' OR customField3__c ='Doe' OR customField3__c ='Doe')
```

Comment: Why is it obvious you can't?  Nothing in your question is obvious.  Is your code a string?  Maybe put in the full line of code, rather than just snippets.  I imagine you're trying to do dynamic SOQL with a standard SOQL query.

Comment: `customField2__c =: strVar1 + strCondition` - its not clear what you are doing - this is neither string nor direct SOQL. Can you show some more relevant code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following syntax is not a dynamic query:

```
List<customObject__c> lstCstObj = [SELECT ... FROM ...];
```

What you need is a dynamic query.  A dynamic query normally looks like:

```
String myQuery = 'SELECT ... FROM ...';
List<customObject__c> lstCstObj = Database.query(myQuery);
```

What you're after is probably something like:

```
// get the parameters
String strVar1 = String.valueOf(RestContext.request.params.get('name'));
String strSurname = String.valueOf(RestContext.request.params.get('surname'));

// create the query string
String myQuery = 'SELECT customField1__c, customField2__c, customField3__c, customField4__c, customField5__c FROM customObject__c WHERE customField2__c = :strVar1';

// add in the surname if it exists
if(String.isNotBlank(strSurname))
{
    myQuery += ' AND (customField3__c = \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(strSurname) + '\' OR customField4__c = \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(strSurname) + '\' OR customField5__c = \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(strSurname) + '\')';
}

List<customObject__c> lstCstObj = Database.query(myQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, except for: WHERE customField2__c = :strVar1'; that should be WHERE customField2__c =\' '+ strVar1 +'\' '; everything works perfect. Really appreciated.